# URL change in zend framework(zend controller router route)

Tags: zend-framework

In zend we have url like this

localhost/project/contact/action/parameter and I want url like this whenever I receive a request on contact us controller then url will become like this

localhost/project/contact-us/action/parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the URL using zend routing. You need to add the route and use this route in "Contact Us" link. You can see the more details at: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html

Hope this answer will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Also, beware that you can create controller with a name such as `Store_MyCustomController` and the routes for it's actions will look something like this:

```
/store/my-custom/action
```